# How does the function get_config_bytes() works?

Tags: php

I am using an extension regarding image uploading which use the function mentioned below and it is a common function which is normally used to get max_upload_size in bytes but I wonder how does it work? 
 For example if $val = 20M then how does it multiply 20M * 1024 and get the correct output in bytes.

```
function get_config_bytes($val) {
            $val = trim($val);
            $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
            switch($last) {
                case 'g':
                    $val *= 1024;
                case 'm':
                    $val *= 1024;
                case 'k':
                    $val *= 1024;
            }
            return $this->fix_integer_overflow($val);
        }
```

I am very curious about this because a while ago when I was using this function it was generating a Notice that non integer is multiply by an integer but now it is working fine. I have no idea what happened. Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if anyone has clue about it.

Comment: The above function will throw a notice on PHP7.1+. Before, if you had a string like `20M` and you used it as a number (performing a mathematical operation on it), it would silently be converted to the number `20`. From PHP 7.1, it would still work but would throw the notice _"A non well formed numeric value encountered"_ unless you've turned off error reporting for notices. [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/Mkbkp)

Comment: Yes but the thing is it is not simply multiplying the 20 * 1024 = 20480. It is producing 20971520 which means it internally multiplying 20*1024*1024 and generating the value in bytes.

Comment: That's because with 20M, the swicth/case that would be matched is `m` and since that case block doesn't have any `break;`, the rule after will be executed as well so it will rather be: `20 * 1024 * 1024`. [Here's an example showing how the switch/case work here](https://3v4l.org/fQ81T)

Comment: ok great! I didn't notice that. Thank you so much. Please mention it as answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I've added my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this question.

### How does it work?

If you pass in `20M`, the `switch/case` would match `case 'm':`. Since the `case`-blocks are missing the `break;` in them, the matched `case`-block will be executed and all other `case`-blocks that comes after. That would result in `20 * 1024 (from the m block) * 1024 (from the k-block)`

[Here's a demo showing how the switch/case works in this context](https://3v4l.org/fQ81T)

### Why do you get notices?

The above function will throw a notice on PHP7.1+. Before, if you had a string like `20M` and you used it as a number (performing a mathematical operation on it), it would silently be converted to the number `20`.

From PHP 7.1, it would still work but would throw the notice *"A non well formed numeric value encountered"* unless you've turned off error reporting for notices.

Here's an updated version that won't throw any notices:

```
function get_config_bytes($val) {
    $val  = trim($val);
    $last = substr($val, -1);   // Get the last character
    $val  = rtrim($val, $last); // Trim away the last character which isn't a number

    switch(strtolower($last)) {
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }

    return $this->fix_integer_overflow($val);
}
```

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/4bbpJ)

I'm sure that there are more efficient ways to do this, but this solves the issue either way.

Comment: I was wondering I need to eliminate the notice. Thanks it cleared my doubts.